# How to Get the Total File size from all document libraries in a site collection based document creation date

Tags: 2013, 2010, document-library

Hi i have some number of files in a document library and i want sum of all file sizes using powershell or any other way i can get the total file size?

i have a site collections and i get total size of documents based on document creation date in between last two months like march to april

Comment: Not a simple question... Do you want to include size of document versions? Content of lists? Pages? Content in the Recycle Bin?

Answer (score 1):

For an approximate total content size for a Site Collection using PowerShell:

```
Get-SPSite http://yourServer/sites/yourSite | select StorageUsed
```

The same from REST API:

```
http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/site/usage
```

Count and size for a single library (excluding versions):

```
Get-SPSite http://yourServer/sites/yourSite | 
  select -ExpandProperty lists | 
  where Title -eq "Documents" | 
  select -ExpandProperty Items | 
  select -ExpandProperty File | 
  measure -Property Length -Sum
```

Count and size of files for an entire Site Collection (excluding versions, list content, and "other"):

```
Get-SPSite http://yourServer/sites/yourSite | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit all | 
  select -ExpandProperty lists | 
  select -ExpandProperty Items | 
  select -ExpandProperty File | 
  measure -Property Length -Sum
```

Comment: Hi Mike, i want to check size only for documents in doc libraries, and how i use above query ?

Comment: Are you asking how to use PowerShell?

Comment: yes how i use above query , and i required total size based on doc creation in between lat two monts